# i can not understand the syntax that how to define xpath in typerscript language

Tags: typescript, react-native, xpath, automation, appium

```js
console.log(client.findElement(xpath,'/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.TextView'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an `Absolute XPath` here, which is inherently harder to read and yields to brittle tests, as this path can be changed in the DOM easily.

If you want to write an XPath that is easier to read and less prone to breaking, you could try using relative notation with the `//` indicator. Here's an example:

Your starting (absolute) XPath:

`'/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.TextView'`

Your new relative XPath:

`//android.widget.ScrollView//android.widget.TextView`

You can also mix absolute and relative XPath, like this:

`//android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.TextView'`

Without a complete page source, I cannot guarantee this XPath will work. The `//` notation means the following element will be located anywhere on the page. This means if you have more than one `android.widget.ScrollView` element on the page, `//android.widget.ScrollView` will return multiple web elements.

This also means if `android.widget.ScrollView` has more than one `android.widget.TextView` element under it, `//android.widget.ScrollView//android.widget.TextView` will locate multiple `TextView` elements.

You can add conditions in brackets such as `android.widget.ScrollView[@class='someClass']//android.widget.TextView` to make your paths more accurate.

If you post a more complete page source, I can help you write better XPaths and understand the notation here.

Comment: You’re welcome, happy to help. If this explanation has helped you, feel free to mark as answer to post, or continue asking questions so we can get to the bottom of your issue.

Comment: Actually i have react-native application and in login page there is a label which name is " create account ". so i got xpath show in question and i want to set click method on that using xpath